# Could not build project with vue cli 3 template due to svg in css

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

While moving to vue-cli 3 I encountered following problem.
I import a plugin's css to my app.scss.

This line: `background-image: url(default-skin.svg);` breaks `yarn build`, which throws this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
```

Here is my vue.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin')

const ASSETS_DIR = 'static'

module.exports = {
  assetsDir: ASSETS_DIR,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('provide-plugin')
        .use(webpack.ProvidePlugin, [{
          axios: "axios",
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery",
          _: "lodash",
          mapGetters: ['vuex', 'mapGetters'],
          mapActions: ['vuex', 'mapActions']
        }])
        .end()
      .plugin('copy-plugin')
        .use(CopyWebpackPlugin, [
          [{
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
            to: ASSETS_DIR,
            ignore: ['.*']
          }]
        ])
        .end()
      .plugin('sprite-loader-plugin')
        .use(SpriteLoaderPlugin)

    config.module
      .rule('svg')
        .test(/\.svg$/)
        .use('file-loader')
          .loader('svg-sprite-loader')
  }
}
```

Any solution?

**update**

[The css which breaks yarn build](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css)

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "f2c",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Victor Ponamariov <victor.ponamariov@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.14.0",
    "fabric": "^2.3.3",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.2.21",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "photoswipe": "^4.1.2",
    "portal-vue": "^1.3.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.25.2",
    "sharer.js": "^0.3.3",
    "stickyfilljs": "^2.0.5",
    "tippy.js": "^2.5.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.6",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.14.0",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.1.1",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-gtm": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-meta": "^1.5.2",
    "vue-mq": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-popperjs": "^1.2.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-select": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.7.4",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-star-rating": "^1.6.0",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^1.5.2",
    "vue-tippy": "^2.0.18",
    "vue-yandex-metrika": "^1.6.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.8.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack-svgstore-plugin": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "$": false,
      "jQuery": false,
      "_": false,
      "axios": false,
      "VK": false,
      "gapi": false,
      "FB": false,
      "mapGetters": false,
      "mapActions": false
    },
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {},
      "postcss-import": {},
      "postcss-url": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

App folder structure:

[image]

Comment: What version of `svg-sprite-loader` are you using? For that matter, could you provide a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm using the latest (3.8.0) version of svg-sprite-loader. I'm not sure how to provide an example on jsfiddle, since it happens only when building a project, it's not a runtime error on a webpage. All I have is: vue cli 3 template with the config I provided, and a .css file I include from external plugin which has .svg in background-image, which breaks build (even though yarn serve works fine). I'd be happy to provide additional information! :)

Comment: You coul share the folder structure, the contents of that `css` file and the contents of your `package.json`, JIC.

Comment: Done. What is JIC? :)

Comment: [JIC](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=JIC) = just in case

Answer (score 4):

*I don't have a fix or full explanation, but there is a workaround...*

The problem seems to be caused by `postcss-import` when importing the CSS file from inside a `<style>` tag of an SFC:

```
// App.vue
<style lang="scss">
  @import 'app.scss'; /* imports default.css -> default-skin.svg */
</style>
```

You can workaround the build error by moving the import into the `<script>` tag (or to `main.js`):

```
// App.vue
<script>
  import 'app.scss'; /* imports default.css -> default-skin.svg */
</script>
```

*see [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-svg-css-buid-issue.git)*

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting node modules folder and then run yarn install again.

If didn't work try:

```
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with navigator object despite the error message. The issue is with svg loader or something like that. Also if I  re-define userAgent, then how would I can be certain what is user's real userAgent?

Answer (score 0):

Ref [vue-pswipe](https://github.com/GuoQichen/vue-pswipe), GuoQichen uses this config for svg.

```js
config.module
  .rule('svg')
  .use('file-loader')
  .clear()
  .loader('url-loader')
  .options({
    limit: 4 * 1024,
    name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
  })
```